# PHP Whether have a database classification retrieval table

Tags: php, mysql

I want store some article into database. I use php and mysql.
Whether have a database classification retrieval table?
like:

```
directory | keyword1 | keyword2 | keyword3 | keyword4|
  sport   | football |    f1    |    nba   |  tennis |
```

so that:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keywordtable WHERE keyword1='$word' OR keyword2='$word' OR keyword3='$word' OR keyword4='$word' ");
```

if some words in the article match one of the keywords, the article will insert into directory - sport.
Thanks.

I need a table like my example, it should be have many words which can let me reference: if my article appears these words, I can put it into the directory it should in. I know there have more and more words which can be defined into `sport`.

Comment: Thats is nice... :) What is the question? (Oh, and rather than having a separate column for each keyword, split the keywords of into another table. That way you can simply do `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE keyword='$word' AND doc_id='$id'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you'd like to have a keyword table against which you can check content.  If the content matches any of the keywords, then the content is tagged with the associated directory.  If that's correct then you need 4 tables:

### keywords

- kword
- dir_id, int not null FK directories

### directories

- dir_id, int not null primary key
- dir_name, varchar

### article_directories

- art_id, int not null FK articles
- dir_id, int not null FK directories

### articles, MyISAM

- art_id, int not null primary key
- art_title, varchar
- content, text FULLTEXT index

  INSERT INTO article_directories(art_id,dir_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT a.art_id, k.dir_id 
      FROM articles a, keywords k 
      WHERE MATCH (a.content) AGAINST (k.kword)

The above query will identify all possible directories that an article could belong to.  This means that an article could belong to *both* 'sports' and 'entertainment', for example.

Comment: @vbence, @Yacoby, I need a table like my example, it should be have many words which can let me reference: if my article appears these words, I can put it into the directory it should in. I know there have more and more words which can be defined into `sport`.

Comment: @cj333: the table structure you've asked for is not normalized and will cause you much future grief. The `keywords` table I've described allows for as many keywords in a directory as you might desire. Say sports has a dir_id=1, you'd insert ('football',1),('tennis',1),('swimming',1) into `keywords`.

Comment: thanks , you taught me new one. But I still want to ask a table, about sport, business, Internet ... I can think football, tennis, swimming, f1 ... these words belong to sport, but I maybe lost many words because I didn't imagine them. I need a professional table if there has. Thanks again.

Comment: @cj333: You can have as many directories with as many keywords as you like. In the directories table, insert 'sports', 'business', 'home', 'misc'.  Have a look and see what the `dir_id`s are.  Then insert into the keywords table using your new keywords and the appropriate `dir_id`s. E.g. ('soccer', 1), ('computer', 2), ('finance', 2), ('kitchen', 3), ('other', 4), ('attic', 3).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fields like `something1` `something2` then you should probably use a different table for them, basically that's what relational databases are for. (Of course there are some legitimate reasons to use something like this, for example caching purposes.)